# Write from file to ArrayList

Tags: java

For the program to work, it is necessary to write data from the file to the arraylist, but how to make the written element not equal to null in the loop? That is, so that the loop stops its execution as soon as it reads all the lines from the file

```
public static void readFromFile(String path, String filename) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> ip = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        File file = new File(path + "\\" + filename);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        ip.add(br.readLine());
        while ((ip.add(br.readLine()) != null)) {
            //writing to a variable
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the existing code?

Comment: You should use try-with-resources to ensure that the `FileReader` is closed after reading from it.

Answer (score 1):

`ip.add(...)` returns a `boolean`. This code won't compile, because a `boolean` is a primitive, and thus can never be null.

Move the `add` inside the loop:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  ip.add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better way to read all lines:

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path_to_file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```